# Dim out downvote answers

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

I just noticed my [downvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26398/stackoverflow-database-design-join-issues/42427#42427) got a different style after a certain number of votes, to look dimmer, lighter. But the links did not followed up and are still dark, widely visible and even more highlighted this way. That's all.

Comment: It is a shaming process...

Comment: What does this have to do with `unanswered-questions`? :)

Comment: @Sampson nothing really. That tag probably entered there due to the auto-complete bugs... I'll change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they just need to add:

```
.downvoted-answer a { color:#666 }
```

Comment: That's correct, but maybe there's more to it than just <A>.

Comment: Not from the looks of it. I could be wrong though.

Comment: There's also a .downvoted-answer { color: #888 }

Comment: @Caw: even if there were, `.downvoted-answer * { color:#666 }` would solve it.

Comment: @JoshK, @voyager If you wanted to change text/links to the same dimmed-color, yes :)

Comment: Jonathan, only the first @ will get notified, per comment. @voyager that seems like it, but I wouldn't be so sure. Also I still can't try it here on Safari.

Comment: @Cawas: No, I think that JoshK was notified as it doesn't appear on my Recent Activity notifications.

Comment: Jonathan, it just came to me, what if there's an image there? It would probably not dim out too... I'll edit to see what happens, but this is the kind of thing that I meant by "maybe there's more to it" ;)

Comment: @Cawas: Considering jQuery is already loaded, images could be faded too :) `$(".downvoted-answer img").fadeTo(0, .5);`

Comment: @voyager, as for notifications Cawas is right: 1) Only the first @ is parsed, no matter how long it is and no matter if a match can be made; 2) If the matched @ refers to yourself, then no notification is triggered; 3) The match should be at least 3 characters, but if there's more characters they should match too (spaces ignored); 4) Umlauts et al will probably work, but only if they're in the display name; funny rewriting of display names will not trigger notifications. (see comments at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees)

Comment: @arj, it's weird because I think that *I* was notified for that comment, but  it was probably Cawas' comment and not Jonathan's. You must be right.