# Should some of the SO related questions be migrated to the real meta SO sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration

Now that [meta SE and meta SO part ways](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/), do you think that some of the questions that are being migrated to this meta SE site should be migrated back to meta SO, especially if they are SO specific?

I can see that from my end, there are a few SO specific questions that shouldn't really belong here in the first place:

1. [The Real SO Database Schema( Not Public Dump)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36279/the-real-so-database-schema-not-public-dump)
2. [What ORM does Stack Overflow use with their ASP.NET MVC project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104970/what-orm-does-stack-overflow-use-with-their-asp-net-mvc-project)
3. [StackOverflow's RentACoder Service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30300/stackoverflows-rentacoder-service)
4. [StackOverflow database design join issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26398/stackoverflow-database-design-join-issues)

Shouldn't they be migrated back to meta SO?

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230189/stack-overflow-meta-migration-historical-questions/230192#230192)

Comment: I believe this is already happening,  but gradually (and only for questions that really need to move)